# Why does Clang warn about unused pointers and unused primitives, but not unused objects?

Tags: c++, clang

In this code snippet...

```
sf::Time obj;
sf::Time* ptr;
int i;
int* p2;
```

The first line doesn't produce a warning, but the other three do. How come?

(Btw, this is an entire method. Nothing is done with the variables.)

Comment: what's the warning?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Objects can have constructors and destructors. So, while you may not be using the actual variable, you may be relying on code that runs in the constructor or destructor.

A good example of this is `std::lock_guard`, which takes advantage of a destructor to unlock a mutex when the lock goes out of scope.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Seems like it would make code less readable though.

Comment: FYI, an example of this would be `std::lock_guard`

Comment: @vu1p3n0x Thanks, that's a good example. I'll add it to my answer.